Why is !Send trait implemented for a RwLockReadGuard and RwLockWriteGuard in Rust?
I recently bumped across issues while trying to make a parallel system using the "Lock Guards" returned by RwLock. I needed to store these locks due to architectural design of my system. To my surprise, the types which stored these Lock Guards in failed to implement the Send trait, which lead me to explore the source code implementation of these guards, and sure enough, I found !Send trait implemented for these types.
I couldn't find any viable explanation for why is the !Send trait implemented for these types. So why is this the defined behaviour in the Rust standard library?
(My guess is that the RwLock uses a sys::RwLock in its structure, which stores an AtomicU32, which must be a thread local state, because in general we cannot transfer anything across thread boundary which is dependent on the thread local state of the thread it was generated lock, but again I'm not really sure)

This is because on some platforms a lock must be released on the same thread it was acquired. Since Rust is using the platform's synchronization primitives, it must adhere to this.
For example, ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(), that is used on Windows <=7.
If you need sendable guards, you can use parking_lot with the send_guard feature.

How is the lock mechanism in parking_lot different from the one in standard lib if it also needs to allocate a lock using the underlying OS call?

@mitesh Because parking_lot does not use the platform's locks. It implements locks manually.

Wouldn't that be inefficient though? But the crates.io page states that it is 1.5x faster.
Are there some algorithmic changes that makes it more efficient?

@mitesh It may surprise, but the synchronization primitives that the OS provides are often slower than possible, sometimes much slower. Modern OSes also provide faster primitives (futexes), and today Rust use those were possible so I don't know if parking_lot is still 1.5x faster (and it is sometimes slower - just today I saw it in a benchmark), but not needing to do a syscall is still an advantage, and I've heard parking_lot is still sometimes faster.

Would you be able to provide some resources where I can understand why this is the case? I understand saving syscalls is a huge benefit, but it might also mean that we compromise soundness, since the OS based primitive can actually use semaphores and atomic operations provided on the core to ensure such locking behavior, but these operations might get premepted in user space.
